Use "Year" as a Factor or a Continuous Variable in a GAMM with Autocorrelation for Modeling Beetle Counts?
I am working on modeling the number of beetles caught in traps over several years using a generalized additive mixed model (GAMM) with an explicitly stated autocorrelation structure. I have one record per trap per year, and data over 7 years from 70 traps.  My model includes various predictors (temperature, drought) and their interactions.
Here is the structure of my current model. I am using tweedie instead of poisson of negbin family, as my data are highly overdispersed (I have tested all threee previously and the tw is simply the best)
library(mgcv)

m.counts.tw <- gamm(sum_ips ~ s(year, k = 6) +
                         s(tmp_z_lag1, k = 5) +
                         s(spei_lag2, k = 8) + 
                         s(x,y, bs = 'gp') + 
                         te(tmp_z_lag1, spei_lag2, k = 20) + 
                         s(site, bs = 're'),
                       data = avg_data_filt, 
                       family = tw,
                       correlation = corAR1(form = ~ year | site))

My goal is to understand the effect of temperature and drought on beetle counts (i have one record per trap, per year).
My questions:

What are the pros and cons of using "year" as a factor versus a continuous variable in this GAMM with autocorrelation?
How might the choice of using "year" as a factor or continuous variable affect the interpretation of the results, especially if I am already accounting the the autocorrelation (correlation = corAR1(form = ~ year | site))?
Are there any best practices or considerations for deciding which approach to take in this type of model?

I believe that correct way is to use year as continuous to account for the temporal trend. My colleague argues that i should instead treat year as a factor f_year to improve predicting power of my climatic variables. In both cases, my predistors are significant, but model with f_year explains less variance that the continuous year.
Any insights or examples from your own experience would be greatly appreciated!

State the R package in which gamm is found.

it is from the mgcv. I have updated the question

Year as a continuous variable makes sense, if you expect a long term trend in one or the other direction. (Given climate change or other ecological changes acting over long time scales, this can be often reasonable --specifically if you have many years of data.)
Year as a factor (specifically as random factor) makes sense, if you have a lot of year-to-year variation that is in some way "random". E.g. year 3 was rather bad due to some extraordinary late frost event during a sensible developmental period, in year 4 you had fewer traps because some broke and in year 6 a tornado was passing through. In this case having year as a random factor helps to account for all the haphazzard year-to-year variation. Every sampling season will be in some ways unique, so adding year as a factor will often make sense.
Now, here comes the maybe surprising part: you can also add year as continuous variable AND as factor in the same model. This is completely fine, if you have reason to believe that you have randon year-to-year variability but also possibly a trend over time due to global warming or habitat change. So, coming back to your question "factor OR continuous variable": both can make sense depending of the nature of your specific study system, and in addition you have also a third option: "factor AND continuous variable".

thank you for your aswer @PuzzledBiologist! Please, is using year as continuous also meaningfull is I have only one record per year? Does the number of observations per year defines is using year as continuous (one observation per year) or random (for several observations per year)? or, if having only one observation per year, is using the autocorrelation term simply enought? Thank you! (I have tested your suggestions of using year as both, but my model did not converge anymore)

Year as continuous variable is still meaningful if you have only one record per year. E.g. a linear regression, where you look at the GDP of a country over 20 years (one data point per year): GDP~Year. Yet, is using year as random variable still meaningful, when you have just one observation per year? Usually not (because the random effect tells you the same thing as the residual error term). If your data set is small, then too many variables can quickly lead to convergence problems --i.e. you have to simplify the model (the random AND continuous suggestion might not work in this case).
